# Laravel 5 - PDF embedding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use XAMPP(windows) on local but the sever runs on Linux.
For embedding a pdf file in HTML I am using:

In controller:

```
$file = public_path() .'/dir/'. $filename; 
return response()->file($file);
```

And in View:

```
<object data="{{ url('/podcast/pdf/'. $data->num . '/' . $data->link_pdf) }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
        </object>
```

This works just fine in local but unfortunately on server nothing appears in html just the browser tries to download the .pdf.

I tried with **headers** but it didn't work:
['content-type' => 'application/pdf']

I'll appreciate any help...